# Moving from SQL to Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am making the journey from an SQL centric world (where I am reasonably fluent) to EF dDbContect with code first and I am struggling. The following is a simplified example; I want to write the following simple SQL query (which took 60 seconds to write):

```
SELECT
    HP.HospitalID
FROM
    Hospitals AS HP
    JOIN NHSTrusts AS NT
    ON NT.NHSTrustID = HP.NHSTrust_NHSTrustID

WHERE
    HP.HospitalName + ', ' + NT.NHSTrustName = 'My hospital name including trust'
```

as an EF style query. I cannot see how to do this and I don't want to drop back into SQL everytime I cannot see how to do something.

Can anyone help:

- On how to frame the above query in EF dbContent
- On a general source of help with

Comment: How `Hospitals` and `NHSTrusts` tables are related?

Comment: please note that `WHERE HP.HospitalName='hospital name' AND NT.NHSTrustName = 'trust'` could potentially be more efficient. Your approach excludes the usage of indexes

Comment: Each trust as a collection of hospitals. A hospital can only belong to one trust. The foreign key is `HP.NHSTrust_NHSTrustID`

Comment: Hi W0lf and thanks . The SQL query was just knocked up quickly as an example; translation is the problem, not efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these entity types:

```
public class Trust
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Hospital> Hospitals { get; set; }
}

public class Hospital
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TrustId { get; set; }
    public Trust Trust { get; set; }
}
```

you'll have this query:

```
dbContext
    .Hospitals
    .Where(h => h.Name + h.Trust.Name == "My hospital name including trust")
    .Select(h => h.Id);
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, many thanks for this. A supplementary question; can any LINQ query also be written using lamda expressions.

Comment: @PeterSmith: these two ways are called "query syntax" and "method syntax" (my sample). You can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx. In most cases, the choice between them is a question of personal preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your entities and DB Context are properly set, here's how your query may look like:

```
var hospitalIds = 
    from hp in dbContext.Hospitals
    where 
        hp.HospitalName == "..." &&
        hp.Trust.NHSTrustName == "..."
    select hp.HospitalId;
```

Of course, this query will have to be materialized by iterating through the results (or by using `.ToList()`/`.ToArray()`).

To define the entities and context properly, refer to this excellent tutorial on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.

Comment: I totally support this! If your relationships are set up properly you can make use of those relationship properties to create a very readable query.

Answer (score 1):

First try some Linq. You can write it as below. The query might have some mistake, it will be corrected by Intellisense.

```
var s  = (from c in Context.Hospitals
          from h in Context.NHSTrusts
          where c.NHSTrust_NHSTrustID==h.NHSTrustID 
          && string.Format("{0},{1}",c.HospitalName,h.NHSTrustName).Equals("My hospital name including trust")

          select c.HospitalId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You would've received my vote if you had used a join statement rather than 2 froms :)

Comment: Hi Amit, that's great. I was using lamda expressions. I really need to read up on LINQ.

Comment: What is the need for two `from` statements (or even `join`), if OP's entities should be related with the foreign key association?

Answer (score 0):

For a good place to get some examples i would recommend  [101 linq samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)
It has everything from using a WHERE to GROUP BY statements.